# Constructing function tangent to $h(x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, derivatives

How do you construct a function $T(x;a)$ for the tangent line to the curve $(sin(4x)+2)^{cos(e^x)} - 1.25$ at the point $x=a=2.2$.

Also shown steps would be much appreciated as I don't want just the answer but rather learn it. Thanks.

Comment: You can find $h'(x)$ from the relation $(\log h(x))'=h'(x)/h(x)$. Of course, the slope of your tangent line is $h'(2.2)$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

The 1st order Taylor series of $h(x)$ about $x = a$,

$$T(x;a) = h(a) + h'(a) (x-a),$$

happens to meet the tangent line to $h(x)$ in $x=a$. Note that this is the point-slope formula for a line given $a$ and $h'(a)$ (slope at $x = a$).

Here is a plot of what I am talking about:

http://www4b.wolframalpha.com/Calculate/MSP/MSP16911bg8ff09gib89a36000049399ii8bef97ahf?MSPStoreType=image/gif&s=32&w=470.&h=179.&cdf=RangeControl

SPOILER: $T(x) = 0.41694 - 0.9088 (x-2.2)$ is your solution $T(x;2.2)$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint : The derivate at x = 2.2 is equal to the slope of the tangent at the
       point ( 2.2 / f(2.2) )