# Derivative (Tangent) of a function

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

What are the steps to constructing the tangent function at the curve $h(x)$? I was looking over this question, [Constructing function tangent to $h(x)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/660027/constructing-function-tangent-to-hx), and I got baffled since I did not know how to answer it. I am just learning the topic and so and I just think it would be good for me if I knew the process before my teacher introduces the topic. So I was wondering if someone could show the steps of how to construct the tangent function to $(sin(4x)+2)^{cos(e^x)} - 1.25$ at some other point, say $x=a=2.0$. As for the given hint by one user, wouldn't $T(x;a) = h(a) + h'(a) (x-a),$ give us $T(x;a) = h(a) + 0$?

Comment: The tangent line must have a variable in it--you can't say "$x=a=2.0$"; rather, you can just say $a=2.0$.

Comment: Have you _graphed_ that function, BTW?  Yeeowie!  At least it's continuous and hasn't gone crazy by $ \ x = 2 \ $ ... Have you learned logarithmic differentiation?  You'll need it to get the derivative function if you really want that particular example.  (And good luck _evaluating_ $ \ h(2) \ $ and $ \ h'(2) \ $ .)

Comment: How about at x=a=1.2 or 1.3? Is there a procedure in constructing the tangent function?

Answer (score 2):

Since the function (egad!) $ \ h(x) \ = \ [2 + \sin \ 4x]^{\cos (e^x)} \ - \ 1.25 \  $ is continuous for all real numbers, it will always be possible to define its derivative function.  We will need the method of logarithmic differentiation for this one:

$$ h'(x) \ = \ \frac{d}{dx} \left(\ [2 + \sin \ 4x]^{\cos (e^x)} \ \right) \ = \ \frac{d}{dx} \left[ e^{\ln (\ [2 + \sin \ 4x]^{\cos (e^x)} \ ) }  \right]  $$

$$ = \  e^{\ln (\ [2 + \sin \ 4x]^{\cos (e^x)} \ )} \ \cdot \ \frac{d}{dx} \left[ \cos (e^x) \ \cdot \ \ln (\ 2 + \sin \ 4x \ ) \   \right]  $$

$$  =  \ [2 + \sin \ 4x]^{\cos (e^x)} \ \cdot \ \left( \cos (e^x)  \cdot \frac{d}{dx} \left[  \ln (\ 2 + \sin \ 4x \ )    \right] \ + \  \frac{d}{dx} \left[ \cos (e^x) \right] \cdot   \ln (\ 2 + \sin \ 4x \ )    \right) $$

$$ = \ \ [2 + \sin \ 4x]^{\cos (e^x)} \ \cdot \ \left( \cos (e^x)  \cdot  \left[  \ \frac{4 \ \cos \ 4x}{ (\ 2 + \sin \ 4x \ )}    \right] \ + \  \left[ - e^x \sin (e^x) \right] \cdot   \ln (\ 2 + \sin \ 4x \ )    \right) $$

The tangent equation at $ \ a = 2 \ $ is then

$$ h(x) \ = \ h(2) \ + \ h'(2) \cdot (x-2) $$

$$ = \ \left( [2 + \sin \ 8]^{\cos (e^2)} \ - \ 1.25 \right)   $$

$$ + \ [2 + \sin \ 8]^{\cos (e^2)} \ \cdot \ \left(   \left[  \ \frac{4 \ \cos \ 8 \ \cos (e^2)}{ (\ 2 + \sin \ 8 \ )}    \right] \ + \  \left[ - e^2 \sin (e^2) \right] \cdot   \ln (\ 2 + \sin \ 8 \ )    \right) \ \cdot \ (x-2)  $$

$$ \approx \  0.38391 \ - \ 7.31987 \ (x-2) .  $$

That looks like it jibes pretty well with the graph...

[image]

$$ \\ $$
The "tangent function" (or *linearization*) at $ \ x = a \ $ is not really any big deal: it follows from the "point-slope" form for the equation of a line, $ \ y - y_0 \ = \ m \ (x - x_0) \ $ .  We are really just writing

$$ f(x) - f(a) \ = \ f'(a) \ \cdot \ (x - a ) \ \ . $$

Comment: That's some really sweet work.

Comment: Took a lot longer to _type_ than to figure out...

Answer (score 0):

The function that is tangent to the curve is the derivative. It is given by the difference quotient $${\lim_{dx \rightarrow 0} \frac {f(x+dx)-f(x)}{dx}}$$ Which is to say that the slope of the tangent line at any one point is the limit of the change in y over the change in x as the change in x approaches zero.

I am sure that the problem your prof will give you will be something much simpler like ${f(x)=x^2}$. So using that as an example: $${\lim_{dx \rightarrow 0}\frac{(x+dx)^2-x^2}{dx}=}$$ $${\lim_{dx \rightarrow 0}\frac{(x^2+2xdx+dx^2)-x^2}{dx}=}$$ $${\lim_{dx \rightarrow 0}\frac{2xdx+dx^2}{dx}=}$$ $${\lim_{dx \rightarrow 0} \frac {(2x+dx)dx}{dx}=}$$ $${\lim_{dx \rightarrow 0}2x+dx=}$$ $${2x}$$ Thus the "curve" that is tangent to ${y=x^2}$ at any point on the curve is ${y'=2x}$

As for finding the derivative of that hairy function, you will need to know the many rules for finding derivatives. By logically applying the rules for derivatives you can find your answer without directly performing the DQ. Not wanting to deprive you of all the fun I will let you find those on your own.